# Referencing forum comments and translating citations using the Harvard citation style

Tags: citations, translations, citation-style

I'm using the Harvard citation style for a paper for the first time in my life, and I can't figure out how to cite specific comments on a web forum. Can I simply treat in like any other web resource, and do something like this:

> On the forum "Name of forum", user "John" says that "Quoting something John wrote on Name of forum". (Name of forum 2013)

I also wonder: When using direct quotes, is it okay to translate these from one language to another or must a direct quote always appear in the language it was written in?

Comment: Please ask one question at a time in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This University of Birmingham document](http://www2.bcu.ac.uk/docs/downloads/health/research/Harvard_Style_Referencing_Guidelines%5B1%5D.pdf) has a comprehensive guide as to cite references from different sources, specifically pages 5-6 have how to cite a forum post.

With regards to your second question, I would translate the quote to the language you are writing in and in the intext reference state "(translated from author, year)".